# Поиск подстроки только в начале или середине слова

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Как настроить сфинкс на частичный поиск только в начале или середине слова, но не в конце.
Например, запрос "очки" должен найти:

- 3D очки
- Очки солнцезащитные

Но не:

- Точки доступа

На данный момент конфиг выглядит так:

```
index products
{
    source            = products
    path              = /var/lib/sphinx/products
    morphology        = stem_ru
    min_word_len      = 3
    min_infix_len     = 3
    index_exact_words = 1
    expand_keywords   = 1
    dict              = keywords
    charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+0435, U+451->U+0435
}
```

Comment: Стоит почитать литературу по регекспам. У Вас "Очки солнцезащитные " есть продолжение строки "Элемент списка" ? Или каким образом "Элемент списка" должен появиться в выборке по  куску "очки"?

Comment: Извиняюсь, "Элемент списка" попал случайно из редактора. Там просто "Очки солнцезащитные". Но да, возможно, решение кроется где-то в регекспах